# Retrive data in combobox from sql server and relation ship btween 2 combx

Tags: vb.net, combobox, relational

i have two combobox and i have two database table in sql server 1st table name is Province and 2nd table name is City if i select province in my 1st combobox then show all cities against selected province show in the 2nd combobox when we click on combobox dropdown list so plz help me how i can do this in vb.net 2010

Answer (score 0):

What do you have so far?
In short you need to add a SelectedIndexChanged or SelectionChangeCommitted event to the Province combobox. Take the selectedValue of the Province combobox and use that to query your cities table and use the results of that to populate the cities combobox.

```
Private Sub cboProvince_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender _
   As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cboProvince.SelectionChangeCommitted

' verify a something was selected 
  If cboProvince.selectedindex>-1 Then
    FillCitiesCombo(cboProvince.selectedValue)
  End If 
End Sub

Private Sub FillCitiesCombo(Province As String)
  dim tmpConn as new sqlconnection(connectionstring)
  tmpConn.open
  try
     Dim sql as string("SELECT CITY FROM CITIES WHERE PROVINCE='"  & Province.tostring & ";")
     Dim adpt As New SQLDataAdapter(sql,tmpConn)
     Dim dt as new datatable
     adpt.fill(dt)
     cboCities.DataSource=dt
     cboCities.ValueMember="City"
     cboCities.DisplayMember="City"
  catch ex as exception

  finally
     tmpConn.Close
  End try
End Sub
```

This is not the most efficient method.  In order to prevent a trip to the database every time a province is selected you can store all the cities into a datatable and then use a dataview with a RowFilter to populate the Cities combobox.